# How to update values inside an object and retain the previous key value pairs in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I need to store the rating selected in local storage , when the user clicks the button the value in it should get stored in the object rate corresponding to the question id.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./rating_button.css";

function Rating(props) {
  let initial = { 1: "", 2: "", 3: "", 4: "", 5: "" };
  const [rate, setRate] = useState(initial);

  const handle = (i) => {
    if (props.id === 1) {
      setRate({ ...rate, 1: i });
    } else if (props.id === 2) {
      setRate({ ...rate, 2: i });
    } else if (props.id === 3) {
      setRate({ ...rate, 3: i });
    } else if (props.id === 4) {
      setRate({ ...rate, 4: i });
    } else {
      setRate({ ...rate, 2: i });
    }
  };

  const user = props.user;

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(user, JSON.stringify(rate));
  }, []);

  const type = props.inputType;
  if (type === "text") {
    return (
      <>
        <textarea value="" onChange={() => handle(this.value)} />
      </>
    );
  }
  return (
    <>
      {props.scale.map((i) => {
        return (
          <button className="rbtn" onClick={() => handle(i)}>
            {i}
          </button>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}

export default Rating;
```

This code does not seem to work, I'm sometimes getting one key value updated but the state does not seem to persist.i'm trying to store the value in the button clicked into the rate object for 5 different questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your useEffect is just running first time, when the component mounts but doesn't subsequently updates as the rate object's state changes after each re-render. It is because of empty dependency array in useEffect, change it to:

```js
useEffect(() => {
 localStorage.setItem(user, JSON.stringify(rate));
},[rate]);
```